# Credit card checker with Luhn algorith javascript

Tags: javascript, luhn

I am currently working on codeacademy's 'Credit Card Checker' using Luhn algorithm, however my code is returning false on valid arrays(which should return). Could you help me resolve the issue?

```js
// All valid credit card numbers
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];
const valid2 = [5, 5, 3, 5, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 8, 7, 5, 1, 4, 3, 9];
const valid3 = [3, 7, 1, 6, 1, 2, 0, 1, 9, 9, 8, 5, 2, 3, 6];
const valid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 0, 6, 8, 2, 9, 0, 5];
const valid5 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 4, 0, 4, 9, 6, 7, 8, 6, 9, 6, 6, 6];

// All invalid credit card numbers
const invalid1 = [4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 1, 0, 9, 1, 7, 9, 5];
const invalid2 = [5, 7, 9, 5, 5, 9, 3, 3, 9, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3];
const invalid3 = [3, 7, 5, 7, 9, 6, 0, 8, 4, 4, 5, 9, 9, 1, 4];
const invalid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 9, 6, 1, 7, 7, 7, 9, 3, 5];
const invalid5 = [5, 3, 8, 2, 0, 1, 9, 7, 7, 2, 8, 8, 3, 8, 5, 4];

// Can be either valid or invalid
const mystery1 = [3, 4, 4, 8, 0, 1, 9, 6, 8, 3, 0, 5, 4, 1, 4];
const mystery2 = [5, 4, 6, 6, 1, 0, 0, 8, 6, 1, 6, 2, 0, 2, 3, 9];
const mystery3 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 3, 7, 7, 0, 2, 0, 9, 6, 2, 6, 5, 6, 2, 0, 3];
const mystery4 = [4, 9, 2, 9, 8, 7, 7, 1, 6, 9, 2, 1, 7, 0, 9, 3];
const mystery5 = [4, 9, 1, 3, 5, 4, 0, 4, 6, 3, 0, 7, 2, 5, 2, 3];

// An array of all the arrays above
const batch = [valid1, valid2, valid3, valid4, valid5, invalid1, invalid2, invalid3, invalid4, invalid5, mystery1, mystery2, mystery3, mystery4, mystery5];


// Add your functions below:

const validateCred = arr => {
  let totalSum = 0;
  let revList = arr.reverse();
  for (let i = 0; i < revList.length; i++) {
    let calcAmount = revList[i];
    if (i !== 0 && i%2 === 0) {
      calcAmount = revList[i] * 2;
      if (calcAmount > 9 ) {
        calcAmount -= 9;
        totalSum += calcAmount;
      } else {
        totalSum += calcAmount;
      }
    } else {
      totalSum += revList[i];
    }
  }
  return (totalSum%10 === 0 ? true : false);
};

console.log(validateCred(valid3))
console.log(validateCred(valid4))
console.log(validateCred(valid5))
```

Comment: I see an error when running your code, is the `sum` in the return statement supposed to be `totalSum`?

Comment: What is `sum` in `return(sum%10 ...`  ? It is not defined in your code.

Comment: it think you have issue with Sum variable. its outside the loop and incorrect as well

Comment: I have already fixed it, but still doesn't resolve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple mistake, check `if (i%2 === 1) {`, algorithm needs to multiply `2` for every second elements

`arr.reverse()` is also bad idea, original array is changed.

```js
// All valid credit card numbers
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];
const valid2 = [5, 5, 3, 5, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 8, 7, 5, 1, 4, 3, 9];
const valid3 = [3, 7, 1, 6, 1, 2, 0, 1, 9, 9, 8, 5, 2, 3, 6];
const valid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 0, 6, 8, 2, 9, 0, 5];
const valid5 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 4, 0, 4, 9, 6, 7, 8, 6, 9, 6, 6, 6];

// All invalid credit card numbers
const invalid1 = [4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 1, 0, 9, 1, 7, 9, 5];
const invalid2 = [5, 7, 9, 5, 5, 9, 3, 3, 9, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3];
const invalid3 = [3, 7, 5, 7, 9, 6, 0, 8, 4, 4, 5, 9, 9, 1, 4];
const invalid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 9, 6, 1, 7, 7, 7, 9, 3, 5];
const invalid5 = [5, 3, 8, 2, 0, 1, 9, 7, 7, 2, 8, 8, 3, 8, 5, 4];

// Can be either valid or invalid
const mystery1 = [3, 4, 4, 8, 0, 1, 9, 6, 8, 3, 0, 5, 4, 1, 4];
const mystery2 = [5, 4, 6, 6, 1, 0, 0, 8, 6, 1, 6, 2, 0, 2, 3, 9];
const mystery3 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 3, 7, 7, 0, 2, 0, 9, 6, 2, 6, 5, 6, 2, 0, 3];
const mystery4 = [4, 9, 2, 9, 8, 7, 7, 1, 6, 9, 2, 1, 7, 0, 9, 3];
const mystery5 = [4, 9, 1, 3, 5, 4, 0, 4, 6, 3, 0, 7, 2, 5, 2, 3];

// An array of all the arrays above
const batch = [valid1, valid2, valid3, valid4, valid5, invalid1, invalid2, invalid3, invalid4, invalid5, mystery1, mystery2, mystery3, mystery4, mystery5];


// Add your functions below:

const validateCred = arr => {
  let totalSum = 0;
  let revList = arr.reverse();
  for (let i = 0; i < revList.length; i++) {
    let calcAmount = revList[i];
    if (i%2 === 1) {
      calcAmount = revList[i] * 2;
      if (calcAmount > 9 ) {
        calcAmount -= 9;
        totalSum += calcAmount;
      } else {
        totalSum += calcAmount;
      }
    } else {
      totalSum += revList[i];
    }
  }
  return(totalSum%10 === 0 ? true : false);
};

batch.forEach(c => console.log(validateCred(c)));
```

Comment: What do you suggest instead of reverse?

Comment: minimum modification to your code could be iterating from right to left `for (let i = revList.length - 1, i >= 0; i--) ...`

Comment: probably add another variable to check odd/even, `i` can't be used.

Comment: Why is `arr.reverse()` a bad idea? The odd/even calc is right to left, so it's either reverse the numbers or go right to left. Using *reverse* makes the odd/even calc simpler.

Comment: @RobG because it changes original array, which might not be intended in a validation function.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite and fixed.

```js
// All valid credit card numbers
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];
const valid2 = [5, 5, 3, 5, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 8, 7, 5, 1, 4, 3, 9];
const valid3 = [3, 7, 1, 6, 1, 2, 0, 1, 9, 9, 8, 5, 2, 3, 6];
const valid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 0, 6, 8, 2, 9, 0, 5];
const valid5 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 4, 0, 4, 9, 6, 7, 8, 6, 9, 6, 6, 6];

// All invalid credit card numbers
const invalid1 = [4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 1, 0, 9, 1, 7, 9, 5];
const invalid2 = [5, 7, 9, 5, 5, 9, 3, 3, 9, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3];
const invalid3 = [3, 7, 5, 7, 9, 6, 0, 8, 4, 4, 5, 9, 9, 1, 4];
const invalid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 9, 6, 1, 7, 7, 7, 9, 3, 5];
const invalid5 = [5, 3, 8, 2, 0, 1, 9, 7, 7, 2, 8, 8, 3, 8, 5, 4];

// Can be either valid or invalid
const mystery1 = [3, 4, 4, 8, 0, 1, 9, 6, 8, 3, 0, 5, 4, 1, 4];
const mystery2 = [5, 4, 6, 6, 1, 0, 0, 8, 6, 1, 6, 2, 0, 2, 3, 9];
const mystery3 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 3, 7, 7, 0, 2, 0, 9, 6, 2, 6, 5, 6, 2, 0, 3];
const mystery4 = [4, 9, 2, 9, 8, 7, 7, 1, 6, 9, 2, 1, 7, 0, 9, 3];
const mystery5 = [4, 9, 1, 3, 5, 4, 0, 4, 6, 3, 0, 7, 2, 5, 2, 3];

// An array of all the arrays above
const batch = [valid1, valid2, valid3, valid4, valid5, invalid1, invalid2, invalid3, invalid4, invalid5, mystery1, mystery2, mystery3, mystery4, mystery5];


function luhnCheck(num) {
  let digit, j, len, odd = true, sum = 0
  const digits = (num + '').split('').reverse()
  for (j = 0, len = digits.length; j < len; j++) {
    digit = parseInt(digits[j], 10)
    if ((odd = !odd)) digit *= 2
    if (digit > 9) digit -= 9
    sum += digit
  }
  return sum % 10 === 0
}

batch.forEach((item) => {
 let number = item.join('')
 console.log(number, luhnCheck(number))
})
```

Ideally, you should pass it in as a string and let the function do the splitting (separation of concerns) as in a real app your want to do various things on the entered number before running luhn like.. cardTypeFromNumber (visa, maestro, dankort, mastercard, amex, dinersclub, discover, chinaunionpay (doesn't use luhn), jcb mostly have all different lengths you wouldn't want to run luhn until you validate the length and format), formatCardNumber, validateCardExpiry, validateCardCVC to name a few.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort, but I don't want to overcomplicate things for now because I am learning the basics yet.

Comment: It's just an exercise, not the real thing. The only reason to do those checks is somewhere in the payment processing system. From a front end point of view, just send it to the payment API and let that work it all out. Otherwise you're just double handling and creating a maintenance issue - new cards, types, checks, number and length ranges, etc. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The [Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) is explained on Wikipedia. Others have answered the question, this is just a different implementation.

```js
function luhnCheck(cardNumber) {
  let nums = cardNumber.split('').reverse();
  let checkValue = nums.shift();
  let luhnSum = nums.reduce((sum, n, i) => {
    let val = n*(i % 2? 1 : 2);
    sum += val > 9? val - 9 : val;
    return sum;
  }, 0);
  return checkValue == 10 - (luhnSum % 10);
}


['4539677908016808', // valid1
 '5535766768751439', // valid2
 '4532778771091795', // invalid1
 '5795593392134643', // invalid2
 '344801968305414',  // mystery1
 '5466100861620239', // mystery2
].forEach(cardNum =>
   console.log(luhnCheck(cardNum))
);
```